Installing crontab
I'm new to Linux and getting the below error when running the crontab -e command.
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/bin
MAILTO=root
0*****ls -la $(find .) | sed -e 's/..csv/#####.csv/g' > /home/ec2-user/companyA/SharedFolders/filteredAudit.csv
error: 
crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.nn8ujc":4: bad minute
errors in crontab file, can't install.


Wrong syntax for your cronjob. See man 5 crontab.

There are many issues with your command. Since this is a user crontab , there should be 5 fields before the command and they should be space or tab-separated. The next error also would be lack of whitespace, this time between the fields and the command; finally ls -la $(find .) will break if a filename contains whitespace and the sed command parsing the output will also probably break, you shouldn't parse ls's output.

Please explain exactly what you're trying to do (by editing your question) and we should be able to suggest a better alternative command to achieve what you're after.
